# jpa embedded class need cachable?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, caching

my entity class is annotated with @Cache, my primary keys are combined of few table fields, primary keys are embedded into this class as embedded class. Do I need to put @Cache for the embedded class as well?

Comment: What is the @Cached annotation (do you mean @Cache)?

Comment: yes :) @Pascal, sorry for typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `@Cache` annotation goes on entities and on collections. Your composite key will be used as key for the cache entry.